# Cannot call method 'match' of undefined handlebars.js

Tags: php, javascript, json, handlebars.js

I am trying to use `handlebars.js` inside PHP. I am grabbing variables passed via `$_GET` building an array and then appending it to `http://my.service.example.com/search.json?. http_build_query($myarray, '', "&");` to buld my URL and then using `file_get_contents` to grab the JSON. I am trying to use `handlebars.js` to display the results. and I am receiving the following error in the Google chrome console

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined
> cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js:431"

when looking at the details of the error in the console I see this

```
lexer.next
cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js:431
lex
cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js:468
lex
cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js:238
parse
cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js:251
Handlebars.parse
cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js:595
compile
cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js:1842
(anonymous function)
cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js:1851
(anonymous function) profile.php:39
```

Here is my template I am using

```html
<script id="ul" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <ul>
   {{#jsonResult}}
     <li>{{name}}</li>
   {{/jsonResult}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

here is my script I am using in an attempt to use the template

```js
var source = $("ul").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var json = $pJSON;
var data1 = JSON.stringify(json);
var data = JSON.parse(data1);
$("body").html(template(data));
```

***this is the line 39 referenced in the console error above `$("body").html(template(data));`***

and finally here is the JSON I am getting (well a sample)

```
{totalCount:2,jsonResult:[{listingId:460880,pageUrl:\/page\/LA\/laplace\/la-carreta-of-laplace\/17-460880.html,name:La
Carreta Of LaPlace,phone:(985) 651-9991,address:107 Carrollwood
Dr,city:Laplace,state:LA,url:http:\/\/www.carretarestaurant.com,latitude:30.44437,longitude:-91.14768,logoUrl:http:\/\/url.com\/imp\/17\/logo\/LG460880.JPG,enticerLine:\Traditional
Flavor Mexican
Cuisine\,photos:[{photoUrl:http:\/\/url.com\/imp\/17\/photo\/PH460880_1_S.jpg,photoDesc:},{photoUrl:http:\/\/url.com\/imp\/17\/photo\/PH460880_2_S.jpg,photoDesc:},{photoUrl:http:\/\/url.com\/imp\/17\/photo\/PH460880_3_S.jpg,photoDesc:},{photoUrl:http:\/\/url.com\/imp\/17\/photo\/PH460880_4_S.jpg,photoDesc:},{photoUrl:http:\/\/url.com\/imp\/17\/photo\/PH460880_5_S.jpg,photoDesc:},{photoUrl:http:\/\/url.com\/imp\/17\/photo\/PH460880_6_S.jpg,photoDesc:},{photoUrl:http:\/\/url.com\/imp\/17\/photo\/PH460880_7_S.jpg,photoDesc:},{photoUrl:http:\/\/url.com\/imp\/17\/photo\/PH460880_8_S.jpg,photoDesc:},{photoUrl:http:\/\/url.com\/imp\/17\/photo\/PH460880_9_S.jpg,photoDesc:},{photoUrl:http:\/\/url.com\/imp\/17\/photo\/PH460880_11_S.jpg,photoDesc:},{photoUrl:http:\/\/url.com\/imp\/17\/photo\/PH460880_12_S.jpg,photoDesc:}]},{listingId:430765,pageUrl:\/page\/LA\/new-orleans\/casa-garcia-mexican-restaurant\/17-430765.html,name:Casa
Garcia Mexican Restaurant,phone:(504) 464-0354,address:,city:New
Orleans,state:LA},{listingId:223993,pageUrl:\/page\/LA\/metairie\/casa-garcia-mexican-restaurant\/17-223993.html,name:Casa
Garcia Mexican Restaurant,phone:(504) 467-4071,address:8814 Veterans
Memorial
Bl,city:Metairie,state:LA,latitude:30.005453,longitude:-90.224346},{listingId:115036,pageUrl:\/page\/LA\/kenner\/casa-tequila\/17-115036.html,name:Casa
Tequila,phone:(504) 443-5423,address:3229 Williams
Bl,city:Kenner,state:LA,latitude:30.014789,longitude:-90.239894,displayAd:http:\/\/url.com\/imp\/17\/disp\/DA115036_658760_1.JPG,displayAds:[{displayAd:http:\/\/url.com\/imp\/17\/disp\/DA115036_658760_1.JPG}]},{listingId:460184,pageUrl:\/page\/LA\/kenner\/garces-latin-american-restaurant\/17-460184.html,name:Garces
Latin American Restaurant,phone:(504) 305-5035,address:4221 Williams
Bl,city:Kenner,state:LA,url:http:\/\/www.garcescubanrestaurant.com,latitude:30.033075,longitude:-90.238324},{listingId:34172784,pageUrl:\/page\/LA\/new-orleans\/taco-bell-new-orleans\/cg-34172784.html,name:Taco
Bell,phone:(504) 286-7901,address:6220 Elysian Fields Ave,city:New
Orleans,state:LA,latitude:30.022314,longitude:-90.061329,enticerLine:Budget-minded
families and travelers make a run for America's leading taco
chain.},{listingId:34184616,pageUrl:\/page\/LA\/new-orleans\/taco-bell-new-orleans-5\/cg-34184616.html,name:Taco
Bell,phone:(504) 391-6930,address:4300 General Degaulle Dr,city:New
Orleans,state:LA,latitude:29.919895,longitude:-90.011082},{listingId:672267490,pageUrl:\/page\/LA\/new-orleans\/taco-bell-new-orleans-4\/cg-672267490.html,name:Taco
Bell,phone:(504) 283-9006,address:4603 Chef Menteur Hwy,city:New
Orleans,state:LA,latitude:30.006073,longitude:-90.035487},{listingId:733204300,pageUrl:\/page\/LA\/new-orleans\/taco-bell-orleans-4\/cg-733204300.html,name:Taco
Bell,phone:(504) 246-6699,address:6007 Bullard Ave,city:New
Orleans,state:LA,latitude:30.043732,longitude:-89.958962},{listingId:733204270,pageUrl:\/page\/LA\/new-orleans\/taco-bell-orleans\/cg-733204270.html,name:Taco
Bell,phone:(504) 244-8761,address:5611 Read Blvd,city:New
Orleans,state:LA,latitude:30.030747,longitude:-89.97091},{listingId:4431549,pageUrl:\/page\/LA\/new-orleans\/taco-bell-orleans-4\/cg-4431549.html,name:Taco
Bell,phone:(504) 821-4458,address:2639 Tulane Ave,city:New
Orleans,state:LA,latitude:29.96146,longitude:-90.089724},{listingId:733204280,pageUrl:\/page\/LA\/new-orleans\/taco-bell-orleans-2\/cg-733204280.html,name:Taco
Bell,phone:(504) 240-6374,address:6009 Bullard Ave,city:New
Orleans,state:LA,latitude:30.044695,longitude:-89.959174},{listingId:4415463,pageUrl:\/page\/LA\/harvey\/taco-bell-harvey\/cg-4415463.html,name:Taco
Bell,phone:(504) 362-0746,address:929 Manhattan
Blvd,city:Harvey,state:LA,latitude:29.902112,longitude:-90.064841,enticerLine:Budget-minded
families and travelers make a run for America's leading taco
chain.},{listingId:34159784,pageUrl:\/page\/LA\/marrero\/taco-bell-marrero-2\/cg-34159784.html,name:Taco
Bell,phone:(504) 341-5367,address:5141 Lapalco
Blvd,city:Marrero,state:LA,latitude:29.874902,longitude:-90.098789},{listingId:34141058,pageUrl:\/page\/LA\/terrytown\/taco-bell-terrytown\/cg-34141058.html,name:Taco
Bell,phone:(504) 394-7584,address:2640 Belle Chasse
Hwy,city:Terrytown,state:LA,latitude:29.888259,longitude:-90.030674},{listingId:612584560,pageUrl:\/page\/LA\/harvey\/taco-bell-harvey-3\/cg-612584560.html,name:Taco
Bell,phone:(504) 374-0972,address:1740 Manhattan
Blvd,city:Harvey,state:LA,latitude:29.88825,longitude:-90.056795},{listingId:708288570,pageUrl:\/page\/LA\/gretna\/taco-bell-gretna\/cg-708288570.html,name:TACO
BELL,phone:(504) 368-3370,address:62 WESTBANK EXPY #
B,city:GRETNA,state:LA,latitude:29.918798,longitude:-90.044141},{listingId:34183917,pageUrl:\/page\/LA\/westwego\/taco-bell-westwego\/cg-34183917.html,name:Taco
Bell,phone:(504) 341-6909,address:1001 Westbank
Expy,city:Westwego,state:LA,latitude:29.898329,longitude:-90.142391},{listingId:672876420,pageUrl:\/page\/LA\/gretna\/taco-party-gretna\/cg-672876420.html,name:Taco
Party,phone:(504) 312-3912,address:1115 van Trump
St,city:Gretna,state:LA,latitude:29.918975,longitude:-90.045341},{listingId:647483470,pageUrl:\/page\/LA\/westwego\/speedy-taco-westwego\/cg-647483470.html,name:Speedy
Taco,phone:(504) 301-1524,address:1020 Bridge City
Ave,city:Westwego,state:LA,latitude:29.930096,longitude:-90.172423}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{{#jsonResult}}
  <li>{{name}}</li>
{{/jsonResult}}
```

`#jsonResult` doesn't iterate over the list like you want it to. You need to use:

```
{{#each jsonResult}}
  <li>{{name}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

See http://handlebarsjs.com#iteration.

You also need to change `var source = $("ul").html();` to `var source = $("#ul").html();`

Comment: your right on track there - I actually forgot the each part - however after correcting this I still seem to have the same issue and error

Comment: Please see the edit.  You aren't providing Handlebars with the correct template.

Comment: I have made the changes this has removed the error however I dont seem to be getting the data into the body tag - I went ahead and published this so you can see what I mean -- http://lstest.siteyp.com/profile.php?listingId=460880&where=new+orleans%2C+LA&what=taco

Comment: There are quite a few things wrong with that source code.  For starters, you're using jQuery before the DOM has finished loading.  If you're going to add HTML to the page with .html() and your JavaScript is in the head tag, make sure you wrap everything in .ready() first.  I have created a jsfiddle that shows everything working, http://jsfiddle.net/PsFDe/.